# How to reorganize the items returned by wp_list_comments()?

Tags: theme-development, customization, comments-template

I'm new to WordPress theme development and learning by building a new theme of my own.
I want to reorganize the items returned by `wp_list_comments()`.

I created `comments.php` in my theme folder and it currently looks like this-

```
<div id="comments">
    <ol class="commentlist">
        <?php
            $comments = get_comments(array(
                'post_id' => XXX,
                'status' => 'approve'displayed
            ));

            wp_list_comments(array(
                'per_page' => 10, 
                'reverse_top_level' => false
            ), $comments);
        ?>
    </ol>
    <?php comment_form(); ?>
</div>
```

Here are the current generated HTML of my theme.

```
<li class="comment byuser comment-author-admin thread-odd thread-alt depth-1" id="comment-4">
    <div id="div-comment-4" class="comment-body">
        <div class="comment-author vcard">
            <img alt="" src="" class="avatar avatar-32 photo" height="32" width="32">
            <cite class="fn">admin</cite>
            <span class="says">says:</span>
        </div>

        <div class="comment-meta commentmetadata">
            <a href="http://mysite.com/post-name/comment-page-1/#comment-4">November 16, 2014 at 4:54 pm</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a class="comment-edit-link" href="http://mysite.com/wp-admin/comment.php?action=editcomment&amp;c=4">(Edit)</a>
        </div>

        <p>This is a comment</p>

        <div class="reply">
            <a class="comment-reply-link" href="/post-name/?replytocom=4#respond" onclick="return addComment.moveForm(&quot;div-comment-4&quot;, &quot;4&quot;, &quot;respond&quot;, &quot;19&quot;)">Reply</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Now I want to reorganize the generated HTML. For example -
I want the `<div class="comment-meta commentmetadata">` go below the `<p>` element.

I saw the structure is defined in the `comment-template.php` inside `wp-include` folder. If I change the HTML structure here I can get my result, but updating WordPress will dismiss all of customization if I do this.

Can anyone help me with a detailed procedure of how can I accomplish this in my theme?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can check for example how the default themes (TwentyXXX) use the *callback* mentioned by @kaiser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `callback` argument for a completely customized rendering of your comment/trackback

```
function wpse168639commentCb( $comment, $args, $depth )
{
    // do whatever you want in here:
    // Dump what you got:
    var_dump( $comment, $args, $depth );
}

wp_list_comments( array(
    # other arguments...
    'callback' => 'wpse168639commentCb',
) );
```